# Does a Hexblade Warlock's Hex Warrior feature allow them to use Thirsting Blade on a non-pact weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, warlock, hexblade

My question is, Can I use Thirsting Blade with my non-Pact weapon?

Example, I have a +3 Magic Longbow that I used the Pact of the Blade ritual to transform it into my Pact Weapon. (I can Only pull this now when I summon it and can't get a sword)

I can use the Hex Warrior to channel my will through 1 weapon I touch to use my Charisma Modifier for the attack and damage rolls. (once per long rest)

Would I still be able to attack twice when taking the attack action with the Sword even though it's not my Pact Weapon?

- The Hex Warrior feature says (XGtE 55-56) :

  > The influence of your patron also allows you to mystically channel your will through a particular weapon. Whenever you finish a long rest, you can touch one weapon that you are proficient with and that lacks the two-handed property. When you attack with that weapon, you can use your Charisma modifier, instead of Strength or Dexterity, for the attack and damage rolls. This benefit lasts until you finish a long rest. If you later gain the Pact of the Blade feature, this benefit extends to every pact weapon you conjure with that feature, no matter the weapon's type.
- Thirsting Blade (PHB 111):

  > You can attack with your pact weapon twice, instead of once, whenever you take the Attack action on your turn.

Answer (score 9):

Thirsting blade says that you can attack twice with your pact weapon. Even if a weapon acts similarly to a pact weapon, if it is not a pact weapon, then it is not a pact weapon, so you can't use thirsting blade with it

Comment: So I'd have to get an Extra Attack Feature from a Multi-Class like a Fighter to be able to Attack twice with the Sword? not much of a point then for having Thirsting Blade :(
@Smart_TJ

Comment: In this case, yes. Thirsting blade *is* designed for a *blade* after all

Comment: Yeah... but then they added XGtE and the Improved Pact Weapon Invocation allowing Bows into the picture.
Been having a lot of fun with this class though, thanks for the ruling!

Comment: @Caleb Thirsting Blade works w Improved Pact Weapon...why would someone need to multiclass? What 'Sword' are you talking about?

Comment: The constraint is that it works for only one weapon at a time, no more and no less.  If you're willing to abide by that constraint, Thirsting Blade works just as well as Extra Attack.

Comment: @aaron9eee I was wanting Extra Attack for a non-pact weapon. As of right now, I have a +3 Magic Longbow, so whenever I summon my Pact Weapon it always takes the form of a +3 Magic Longbow.
I wanted to pick up a Longsword and a Shield so that I could jump into Melee Combat with it, but I won't benefit from Thirsting Blade.

Comment: Also, don't forget, that Longbow does not fulfill the Hex Warrior criteria: "that lacks the two-handed property"